# How to get information from Object in class in Parse.com using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have in parse.com the class `MainBranch` and it contains objects in columns `Customer` and `Location` which are pointing to another classes ((`User` and `locations` )) and I need some information from those two classes but I can not reach to them.

My output after running give me `[Object Object]`

My `JavaScript` code :

```
    var order = Parse.Object.extend("MainBranch");
    var query = new Parse.Query(order); 

    query.find({
        success: function(results) {

        alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " Orders.");

        var orid1 = results[2].get("OrderId")
        document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML = orid1;

        orid1 =  results[2].get("Customer");
        document.getElementById("intro1").innerHTML = orid1;

        orid1 =  results[2].get("TotalPrice");
        document.getElementById("intro2").innerHTML = orid1;

        orid1 =  results[2].get("Location");
        document.getElementById("intro3").innerHTML = orid1;

        orid1 =  results[2].get("Date");
        var orid2 =  results[2].get("Time");
        document.getElementById("intro4").innerHTML = orid1+"<br>"+orid2;

        },
        error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
        });
```

from my searching I found that relations are necessary thus I tried many ways but i did not undrestand relations clearly and I did not find the solution yet. any help please !!

Comment: Do you have any idea how to solve my problem ? @BarbaraLaird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include those objects using

```
query.include("Customer");
query.include("Location");
```

This will fetch the related objects together with the MainBranch objects:

```
var customer = results[2].get("Customer");
```

Comment: I do like you said and then I added -- customer.get("username"); -- because I need the user name, Is it correct ? because it gave me output: undefined @Handsomeguy

Comment: Thank u very much it works well ,, just I change some places and it worked Thaaaaanks @Handsomeguy

Comment: customer object worked correctly but location object is not !! despite I code them exactly the same .. Is it affect if i use two includes ?!!! do u have any idea? @Handsomeguy

Comment: You can use include on several pointers. What kind of object is Location? Are you sure the object you're checking really has a location?

Comment: oh ya this is the problem , there is no real location in database lol @Handsomeguy Thank u man u really made my day and I feel I am idiot lol

Comment: Hehe, no problem. Glad to have helped. Good luck with your app

Comment: another question I hope it is the last and sorry if i am bothering you.. I am getting data from parse.com and save it in html table and i am using id in each cell of the row .. My question is ,, is there a way to make number of rows in html table exactly like number of rows in parse.com ? @Handsomeguy

Comment: Most probably, but you should create a new question for that tagged with html. You will probably get a better answer then :-)